# Import Dataflow Profile not importing product correctly

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to `import` a product into `Magento` using the `Dataflow Profiles`. After uploading and running the file, I get a successful message, but I don't see the products under the `admin->catalog->manage products`. I went into the database to see if it appeared in `catalog_product_entity`. It appears, but the `sku` is `NULL`(it isn't null in the csv file). I suspect this is why it's not showing up in `admin->catalog->manage products`, but when I change the `sku` it still doesn't show up. I have the following:

### **Dataflow Profile**

---

[image]

### **Success Message**

---

[image]

### **Database Screenshot** - entity_ids 9-20 are my attempts

---

[image]

I've tried the following:

- Changing `sku` Value in database to something other than `NULL`cleared cache and reindexed
- Confirmed that the `image` was imported each time I tried the import.
- I confirmed that some of the fields where imported into the database, such as `type`. I don't know what other fields would prevent the image from showing up in `manage products`.

Anyone know what could be the possible reason?

Comment: If this helps, I accidentally deleted the default Dataflow Profile "Import All Products", so I had to recreate it. I just used all of the same settings. I'm not sure if it worked before or not, because this is the first time, that I'm attempting to import.

Answer (score 0):

1 - After you make changes directly to DB you should clear cache and ro reindex in Magento

2 - If you use Excel CSV - Magento profile should have csv seperator set to ";"

Comment: thanks for the quick response, I cleared the cache and reindexed. Also, are you sure that CSV seperator should be set to ";"? the default is "," it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a screen shot of the your dataprofile's options tab?   Secondly please post your header row of your CSV into Stack. Issues like these often have nothing to do with DB / Cache, most often issues like these pertain to the csv having the wrong line ending type, or the header row has columns named incorrectly.